# Setting up Intellij IDEA for Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Having tried the two other popular IDEs for this language, I decided that IntelliJ would work best for me. Still haven't managed to get it to work properly (e.g. getting the console running to test out new scripts, running a script from the IDE itself without create complicated project structures around it, etc.) and haven't found any descent tutorial for it. There were no problems in the installation and I have managed to get a simple "hello world" application to run (with a lot of additional overhead though). Is this what is expected from this IDE when running Scala?

I have some experience with programming (Java, C#, R, and Matlab) and I've worked with Eclipse, Netbeans, and Visual Studio, but I never encountered so many issues with getting a language to run smoothly on an IDE (in the case of scala, it is actually simpler for me to write my scripts on Notepad++ and then run them through the command prompt, though it is a quite cumbersome process). I'd appreciate any advice on this matter.

I'm using IntelliJ 14 and Scala 2.11.4 on a Windows 7 PC.

Answer (score 0):

From the IDEA (Scala and SBT plugins must be installed):
Steps:

> Create Project -> Scala -> SBT -> (Choose scala version and SBT
>   version) -> Finish!

That's all.

From console:

```
cmd 
sbt
set name := "Poject name" 
set version := "0.1" 
set scalaVersion := "2.11.5"
session save
```

Now it's possible to open it in IDEA.